# Google+ Accidental Add to Circle

Tags: google-plus

Accidentally added someone I really shouldn't have added on Google+ and 2 seconds later, upon realising the mistake, un-added. Will that person still receive an email with my name? Or did I cancel the action fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the users notification settings. They could get notified by email and/or the bell dropdown. There is a good chance a notification is available to them but if they are likely to see it or not depends on the person.